Instagram Graph API - Pages list returns empty (/me/accounts)
I am trying to set up an Instagram Graph API integration.
The problem in short: when trying to query the GET /me/accounts endpoint, i get an empty data list (pages list). And that makes me unable to continue with data fetching (beacuse I need his instagram user id).
Details:

My instagram app is not live yet, still in development (yet to go through app review process)
Im trying to do it with an access token of a friend (for my account it works). I think I completed all the prerequisites for that to be possible: added his developer account as a developer in my app, he connected the instagram account to the facebook page, i got the access token with the following permissions: instagram_basic,pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement,instagram_manage_insights
The same flow works for my account
The same result received when using the Graph API Explorer
Im basically trying to set up with those two guides (tried both ways, still empty list): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/business-login-for-instagram


Solved:
All I had to do was add the 'business_management' permission

Hey did you undergo app review for business_management and they accepted even if its only messaging solution usecase as it mentions here the "allowed_usage" is for ads related usecases https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/

@Moe Sorry I didnt undergo app review, and I am not using messaging
